Estimate probability density function (PDF) from a set of percentiles and standard deviation
I have a reverse engineering problem: a CDF with 7 percentiles (CDF_7) as plain text, and a standard deviation. I used the CDF_7 percentiles to calculate a PDF. The PDF I calculated (left, green) (using the exported data CDF_7, blue) is different from the PDF in the machine (right, red). Ideally the PDFs should be equal.

What am I doing wrong? In the function below I am interpolating values between the percentiles. Could it be useful to involve the standard deviation in solving this problem? Any thoughts how the standard deviation can be useful here for making a correct PDF?
My Python code:
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        
        def epdf_hist(cdf_7pct, pct, bins_std):
            """Makes histogram - Empirical Probability Density Function (PDF) - based on
            7 percentilevalues of a Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF)
            The 7 percentilevalues are interpolated to 100 values and then binned
            :parameter
                cdf_7pct: 1-dimensional array containing 7 values, sorted high to low
                pct: 7 percentiles, typically [1,5,10,50,90,95,99]
                bins_std: 1-dimensional array containing bins, width = 0.2
            :returns
                pdf of 100 interpolated, binned values,
                bins
                100 interpolated values
            """
            d_pct = np.diff(pct)
            cdf_100pct = [] # make 100 values
            # interpolate between given percentile values
            for i in range(0, len(d_pct)):
                arr = np.linspace(cdf_7pct[i], cdf_7pct[i + 1], num=d_pct[i], endpoint=False) #laatste interpolatiepunt niet meenemen
                cdf_100pct.extend(arr)
            cdf_100pct.extend([cdf_7pct[-1]]) # add last 
            cdf_100pct.extend([min(cdf_7pct)+(min(cdf_7pct) - min(arr))]) # add one extra
            count, bins_count = np.histogram(cdf_100pct, bins=bins_std)
            return count, bins_count, cdf_100pct
        
        # cumulative distribution function (CDF_7) exportdata
        data = np.array([42.38, 42.31,  42.23,  42.03,  41.83,41.81,41.66])
        perc = [1,5,10,50,90,95,99]
        stdev = 0.15
        
        # values CDF from  machine
        targetbins = np.array([41.6,41.8, 42.0, 42.2,42.4])
        c_targetperc = np.array([100,97,58,12,0])
        # values PDF from machine
        p_targetperc = np.array([3,39,46,12,0])
        
        # calculations
        epdf_hist_count, epdf_hist_binscount, cdf_100pct = epdf_hist(data, perc, targetbins)
        # figure
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 4), layout="constrained")
        axs = fig.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
        axs[0].hist(cdf_100pct,bins=targetbins, density=False, color = 'green', alpha = 0.5, label="PDF i calculated from CDF_7")
        axs[1].bar(targetbins,p_targetperc, color='red', edgecolor='black', width=0.2, align='edge', alpha = 0.5, label="PDF in  machine")
        axs[1].plot(data,perc, 'bo--', label="export from machine: CDF_7")
        fig.suptitle("comparison of distributions")
        for ax in axs:
            ax.grid(True)
            ax.legend()
            ax.set_xlabel("dB")
            ax.set_ylabel("Probability of occurrence")
            ax.label_outer()
        plt.show()


Welcome to Cross Validated! Your "CDF" is a decreasing function, and CDFs do not decrease, so I am not sure how to address your problem.

@Dave This is probably a different convention, referred to by most statisticians as a complementary CDF or survival function.  The question, though, appears to ask us to debug the code.  Kris, could you state in English (or math) what your question is so that we can determine it's not simply a coding issue?

The CDF in acoustics is by convention presented decreasing.  By interpolating the 7 values of the cdf i actually differentiated the curve i guess. My question is: how can the stdev contribute to making this pdf. Thanks!

Make sure to add that information to the question as folks do not always read all the comments.

Why do you expect the PDFs to match?

I am not sure if it is utopic. Perhaps there is more data in the machine than the machine spits out with the 7 percentiles. However, i am sceptic about my own calculation because there is an error and  i don 't use the stdev. I would like to get some inspiration to do more testing and reduce the error. How would you approach this?

To exploit additional information you could employ the method of moments or maximum likelihood.  Because you have have supplied only generic information about your application, we can't give you any more than such a generic answer.  In particular, with no information available about the "machine," we have no basis for comparing your PDF with what it might spit out.

I have given this question a light copy-edit to help it read better and made the title better reflect the question, since you don't in fact have access to the whole CDF merely 7 percentiles and the standard deviation. If you think I have inadvertently changed the meaning of some aspect of your question, feel free to revert.
